# What is the proper way to get input from the motion controllers touch pads?

Tags: unity, c#, htc-vive

I've been trying to figure out how to get the inputs from the touch pads on the motion controllers but have yet to find out how to do so. Initially I tried doing the following (as it was how I accessed the triggers and the side buttons)...

```
private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId gripButton = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Grip; //Essentially this is accessing
                                                                               //SteamVR_TrackedObject.cs and telling our script
                                                                               //and defining it here.


private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId triggerButton = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Trigger;
private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId Axis0 = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis0;
private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId Axis1 = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis1;
private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId Axis2 = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis2;
private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId Axis3 = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis3;
private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId Axis4 = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis4;
```

I know I got the buttons right but I'm not sure if I'm getting the touch pad inputs properly. Also the other issue I'm having is how do I differentiate between controllers?

For context here is my script in full (which is based upon [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZTctk19sx8) video)...

```
public class WandController : MonoBehaviour {
    private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId gripButton = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Grip; //Essentially this is accessing
                                                                                   //SteamVR_TrackedObject.cs and telling our script
                                                                                   //and defining it here.


    private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId triggerButton = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Trigger;
    private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId Axis0 = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis0;
    private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId Axis1 = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis1;
    private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId Axis2 = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis2;
    private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId Axis3 = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis3;
    private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId Axis4 = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis4;

    private SteamVR_Controller.Device controller { get { return SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index); } }
    private SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;

    private GameObject pickup;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        trackedObj = GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedObject>();
    } 

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (controller == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Controller not initalized");
            return;
        }

        if (controller.GetPressDown(gripButton) && pickup != null)
        {
            pickup.transform.parent = this.transform;
        }
        if (controller.GetPressUp(gripButton) && pickup != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Grip button was unpressed");
        }

        if (controller.GetAxis(Axis0).x >= 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Axis0 detected");
        }
        if (controller.GetAxis(Axis1).x >= 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Axis1 detected");
        }
        if (controller.GetAxis(Axis2).x >= 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Axis2 detected");
        }
        if (controller.GetAxis(Axis3).x >= 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Axis3 detected");
        }
        if (controller.GetAxis(Axis4).x >= 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Axis4 detected");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        pickup = collider.gameObject;
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider)
    {
        pickup = collider.gameObject;
    }
}
```

Also here is the script where I retrieved all the inputs...

```
//========= Copyright 2015, Valve Corporation, All rights reserved. ===========
//
// Purpose: Wrapper for working with SteamVR controller input
//
// Example usage:
//
//  var deviceIndex = SteamVR_Controller.GetDeviceIndex(SteamVR_Controller.DeviceRelation.Leftmost);
//  if (deviceIndex != -1 && SteamVR_Controller.Input(deviceIndex).GetPressDown(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
//      SteamVR_Controller.Input(deviceIndex).TriggerHapticPulse(1000);
//
//=============================================================================

using UnityEngine;
using Valve.VR;

public class SteamVR_Controller
{
    public class ButtonMask
    {
        public const ulong System           = (1ul << (int)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_System); // reserved
        public const ulong ApplicationMenu  = (1ul << (int)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_ApplicationMenu);
        public const ulong Grip             = (1ul << (int)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Grip);
        public const ulong Axis0            = (1ul << (int)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis0);
        public const ulong Axis1            = (1ul << (int)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis1);
        public const ulong Axis2            = (1ul << (int)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis2);
        public const ulong Axis3            = (1ul << (int)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis3);
        public const ulong Axis4            = (1ul << (int)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis4);
        public const ulong Touchpad         = (1ul << (int)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Touchpad);
        public const ulong Trigger          = (1ul << (int)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Trigger);
    }

    public class Device
    {
        public Device(uint i) { index = i; }
        public uint index { get; private set; }

        public bool valid { get; private set; }
        public bool connected { get { Update(); return pose.bDeviceIsConnected; } }
        public bool hasTracking { get { Update(); return pose.bPoseIsValid; } }

        public bool outOfRange { get { Update(); return pose.eTrackingResult == ETrackingResult.Running_OutOfRange || pose.eTrackingResult == ETrackingResult.Calibrating_OutOfRange; } }
        public bool calibrating { get { Update(); return pose.eTrackingResult == ETrackingResult.Calibrating_InProgress || pose.eTrackingResult == ETrackingResult.Calibrating_OutOfRange; } }
        public bool uninitialized { get { Update(); return pose.eTrackingResult == ETrackingResult.Uninitialized; } }

        // These values are only accurate for the last controller state change (e.g. trigger release), and by definition, will always lag behind
        // the predicted visual poses that drive SteamVR_TrackedObjects since they are sync'd to the input timestamp that caused them to update.
        public SteamVR_Utils.RigidTransform transform { get { Update(); return new SteamVR_Utils.RigidTransform(pose.mDeviceToAbsoluteTracking); } }
        public Vector3 velocity { get { Update(); return new Vector3(pose.vVelocity.v0, pose.vVelocity.v1, -pose.vVelocity.v2); } }
        public Vector3 angularVelocity { get { Update(); return new Vector3(-pose.vAngularVelocity.v0, -pose.vAngularVelocity.v1, pose.vAngularVelocity.v2); } }

        public VRControllerState_t GetState() { Update(); return state; }
        public VRControllerState_t GetPrevState() { Update(); return prevState; }
        public TrackedDevicePose_t GetPose() { Update(); return pose; }

        VRControllerState_t state, prevState;
        TrackedDevicePose_t pose;
        int prevFrameCount = -1;
        public void Update()
        {
            if (Time.frameCount != prevFrameCount)
            {
                prevFrameCount = Time.frameCount;
                prevState = state;

                var system = OpenVR.System;
                if (system != null)
                {
                    valid = system.GetControllerStateWithPose(SteamVR_Render.instance.trackingSpace, index, ref state, ref pose);
                    UpdateHairTrigger();
                }
            }
        }

        public bool GetPress(ulong buttonMask) { Update(); return (state.ulButtonPressed & buttonMask) != 0; }
        public bool GetPressDown(ulong buttonMask) { Update(); return (state.ulButtonPressed & buttonMask) != 0 && (prevState.ulButtonPressed & buttonMask) == 0; }
        public bool GetPressUp(ulong buttonMask) { Update(); return (state.ulButtonPressed & buttonMask) == 0 && (prevState.ulButtonPressed & buttonMask) != 0; }

        public bool GetPress(EVRButtonId buttonId) { return GetPress(1ul << (int)buttonId); }
        public bool GetPressDown(EVRButtonId buttonId) { return GetPressDown(1ul << (int)buttonId); }
        public bool GetPressUp(EVRButtonId buttonId) { return GetPressUp(1ul << (int)buttonId); }

        public bool GetTouch(ulong buttonMask) { Update(); return (state.ulButtonTouched & buttonMask) != 0; }
        public bool GetTouchDown(ulong buttonMask) { Update(); return (state.ulButtonTouched & buttonMask) != 0 && (prevState.ulButtonTouched & buttonMask) == 0; }
        public bool GetTouchUp(ulong buttonMask) { Update(); return (state.ulButtonTouched & buttonMask) == 0 && (prevState.ulButtonTouched & buttonMask) != 0; }

        public bool GetTouch(EVRButtonId buttonId) { return GetTouch(1ul << (int)buttonId); }
        public bool GetTouchDown(EVRButtonId buttonId) { return GetTouchDown(1ul << (int)buttonId); }
        public bool GetTouchUp(EVRButtonId buttonId) { return GetTouchUp(1ul << (int)buttonId); }

        public Vector2 GetAxis(EVRButtonId buttonId = EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Touchpad)
        {
            Update();
            var axisId = (uint)buttonId - (uint)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis0;
            switch (axisId)
            {
                case 0: return new Vector2(state.rAxis0.x, state.rAxis0.y);
                case 1: return new Vector2(state.rAxis1.x, state.rAxis1.y);
                case 2: return new Vector2(state.rAxis2.x, state.rAxis2.y);
                case 3: return new Vector2(state.rAxis3.x, state.rAxis3.y);
                case 4: return new Vector2(state.rAxis4.x, state.rAxis4.y);
            }
            return Vector2.zero;
        }

        public void TriggerHapticPulse(ushort durationMicroSec = 500, EVRButtonId buttonId = EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Touchpad)
        {
            var system = OpenVR.System;
            if (system != null)
            {
                var axisId = (uint)buttonId - (uint)EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis0;
                system.TriggerHapticPulse(index, axisId, (char)durationMicroSec);
            }
        }

        public float hairTriggerDelta = 0.1f; // amount trigger must be pulled or released to change state
        float hairTriggerLimit;
        bool hairTriggerState, hairTriggerPrevState;
        void UpdateHairTrigger()
        {
            hairTriggerPrevState = hairTriggerState;
            var value = state.rAxis1.x; // trigger
            if (hairTriggerState)
            {
                if (value < hairTriggerLimit - hairTriggerDelta || value <= 0.0f)
                    hairTriggerState = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (value > hairTriggerLimit + hairTriggerDelta || value >= 1.0f)
                    hairTriggerState = true;
            }
            hairTriggerLimit = hairTriggerState ? Mathf.Max(hairTriggerLimit, value) : Mathf.Min(hairTriggerLimit, value);
        }

        public bool GetHairTrigger() { Update(); return hairTriggerState; }
        public bool GetHairTriggerDown() { Update(); return hairTriggerState && !hairTriggerPrevState; }
        public bool GetHairTriggerUp() { Update(); return !hairTriggerState && hairTriggerPrevState; }
    }

    private static Device[] devices;

    public static Device Input(int deviceIndex)
    {
        if (devices == null)
        {
            devices = new Device[OpenVR.k_unMaxTrackedDeviceCount];
            for (uint i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
                devices[i] = new Device(i);
        }

        return devices[deviceIndex];
    }

    public static void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < OpenVR.k_unMaxTrackedDeviceCount; i++)
            Input(i).Update();
    }

    // This helper can be used in a variety of ways.  Beware that indices may change
    // as new devices are dynamically added or removed, controllers are physically
    // swapped between hands, arms crossed, etc.
    public enum DeviceRelation
    {
        First,
        // radially
        Leftmost,
        Rightmost,
        // distance - also see vr.hmd.GetSortedTrackedDeviceIndicesOfClass
        FarthestLeft,
        FarthestRight,
    }
    public static int GetDeviceIndex(DeviceRelation relation,
        ETrackedDeviceClass deviceClass = ETrackedDeviceClass.Controller,
        int relativeTo = (int)OpenVR.k_unTrackedDeviceIndex_Hmd) // use -1 for absolute tracking space
    {
        var result = -1;

        var invXform = ((uint)relativeTo < OpenVR.k_unMaxTrackedDeviceCount) ?
            Input(relativeTo).transform.GetInverse() : SteamVR_Utils.RigidTransform.identity;

        var system = OpenVR.System;
        if (system == null)
            return result;

        var best = -float.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < OpenVR.k_unMaxTrackedDeviceCount; i++)
        {
            if (i == relativeTo || system.GetTrackedDeviceClass((uint)i) != deviceClass)
                continue;

            var device = Input(i);
            if (!device.connected)
                continue;

            if (relation == DeviceRelation.First)
                return i;

            float score;

            var pos = invXform * device.transform.pos;
            if (relation == DeviceRelation.FarthestRight)
            {
                score = pos.x;
            }
            else if (relation == DeviceRelation.FarthestLeft)
            {
                score = -pos.x;
            }
            else
            {
                var dir = new Vector3(pos.x, 0.0f, pos.z).normalized;
                var dot = Vector3.Dot(dir, Vector3.forward);
                var cross = Vector3.Cross(dir, Vector3.forward);
                if (relation == DeviceRelation.Leftmost)
                {
                    score = (cross.y > 0.0f) ? 2.0f - dot : dot;
                }
                else
                {
                    score = (cross.y < 0.0f) ? 2.0f - dot : dot;
                }
            }

            if (score > best)
            {
                result = i;
                best = score;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

So anyone know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled upon this looking for something else.

`SteamVR_Controller.Device` has a method `GetAxis()` (as you have already tried using) and the default parameter is the touchpad so you don't want to pass any value. That will return the `Vector2` position on the touchpad that you are touching.

`controller.GetAxis()` should be all you need. The returned `Vector2` goes from `(-1, -1)` to `(1,1)` so just check the value isn't `(0,0)`:

```
Vector2 value = controller.GetAxis();
if(value != Vector2.zero)
    DoSomething(value);
```